# Is "rid" a noun in "I want rid of him"?

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives

*The Oxford Dictionary* regards ***rid*** as a *verb* only.

However, is ***rid*** a noun in ***I want rid of him***?

If ***rid*** is a past participle, then, can it be followed by ***want***?

Comment: This is a nonstandard usage.  I would probably say "rid" is a past participle, making this analogous to the passive forms "I am rid of him" and "I got rid of him".  In that sense, yes, it is a verb.

Comment: Is it correct that ***want + adjective*** or ***want + p.p.*** for ***want***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want rid of him.

This is a reduced form of  *I want **to be** rid of him.*

**Rid** is a past participle.

From [Using English](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/rid.html)

> To Rid : To dispose of
>
> Conjugation of verb 'Rid'
>
> V1 Base Form (Infinitive):    To Rid
>
> V2 Past Simple:   Rid/Ridded
>
> V3 Past Participle:   Rid/Ridded
>
> V4 3rd Person Singular:   Rids
>
> V5 Present Participle/Gerund: Ridding

Comment: Is it common in English for this type of reduced form? or just being seen in such a special informal, non-standard idiom?

Comment: The GloWbE corpus shows that this expression is overwhelmingly British English (116 examples in GB, 14 in IE, against 27 from all other areas together). However, I don't think it is general BrE: the construction "want + PP" (eg "wants washed") is regional: I hear it in Yorkshire where I live now, but didn't in Southern England where I grew up.

Comment: @Colin Fine I haven't heard it for some time, but it was once unremarkable in Oldham. Unlike say "The car needs washed".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Are you saying that you **do** hear _needs washed_ now but not _wants washed_, or that _needs washed_ was always remarkable. Now I think about it, I think _needs washed_ is more common than _wants washed_.

Comment: @Colin "I want rid of this dog!" was once not all that uncommon here, but "The car needs/wants washed" has always been regarded as a Scottishism.

Comment: _Rid_ is a strange verb; it's part of the _set, fit, let_ monosyllabic uninflected verb class, and obligatorily causative. It also requires _of_ to designate the riddance.

Comment: @ColinFine I grew up in northern Derbyshire, I've worked with and lived with Yorkshire people, and also lived in Yorkshire but I've only recently become aware of "needs washed" and I certainly don't think of it as a Yorkshire or other northern English construction. I first became aware of it as an Irish construction but particularly Northern Irish so I'd accept Edwin Ashworth's contention that it's Scottish (although I can't remember my Ulster/Scots grandfather using it).